# Are these examples of polymorphism?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

After browsing some questions about **polymorphism**, it seems that polymorphism is a general idea in Java that allows an object to behave as if it were an instance of another class; thus code is more independent from the concrete class. Given this idea, are the two method calls in the following `main()` method usages of polymorphism?

```
abstract class A
{
  void f() { System.out.println("A.f()"); }
  abstract void g();
}

class B extends A
{
  void g() { System.out.println("B.g()"); }
}

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    A a = new B();
    a.f();        // Is this an example of Polymorphism?
    a.g();        // ...
  }
}
```

The **output** is:

```
A.f();  
B.g();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Polymorphism** – means the ability of a single variable of a given type to be used to reference objects of
different types, and automatically call the method that is specific to the type of object the variable references. In a
nutshell, polymorphism is a bottom-up method call. **The benefit of polymorphism is that it is very easy to add new
classes of derived objects without breaking the calling code** (i.e. getTotArea() in the sample code shown
below) that uses the polymorphic classes or interfaces. When you send a message to an object even though you
don’t know what specific type it is, and the right thing happens, that’s called ***polymorphism***. The process used by
object-oriented programming languages to implement polymorphism is called ***dynamic binding***.

[image]

> it seems that Polymorphism is a general idea in Java

**Polymorphism**, **inheritance** and **encapsulation** are the 3 pillar of an object-oriented language(Not Java only).

Answer (score 6):

Both are examples of polymorphism. The `B` is behaving like an `A`.  (I previously missed the `abstract void g()` declaration.  Or did you add it while we were answering??)

However, in this case "an `A`" is a bit rubbery.  Since `A` is `abstract` you can't have an object that is an `A` and not an instance of some other class.

Comment: No, I didn't edit my question. Btw, How do you think about Ean's answer below ?

Comment: I disagree with it :-).  You are calling a method on a B instance *as if* it was an A instance in both cases.  That's polymorphism in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

Only `a.g()` is polymorphism. As you have a reference of type `A` but its calling the method in object `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather say they should behave as instances of the same class. The derived members should obey the general contract documented in the javadoc.

I would recommend you to read the wiki article and also take a look at the concepts of **dynamic binding**.

In short: the concrete invoked method depends on the runtime type of the referenced object **not** on the type of the referencing variable.